# How to create 2 individual daisy chains using the MAX7219 Module and Mega2560

Tags: arduino-mega, spi, display, 7-segment, max7219

I am using MAX7219 8 digit 7 segment displays with Arduino Mega2560. Now, I have to physically space out the displays far from each other. Hence, after a certain distance the displays on the far end start flickering. So, can we setup 2 individual daisy chains using the MAX7219 module with Arduino Mega2560.

Thanks for helping out in advance.